# Regex find keyword followed by N characters

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a df column with URL having keyword with hash values,
example

```
/someurl/env40d929fadbe746ecagjbf6c515d30686/end
/some/other/url/envlabel40d929fadbe746ecagjbf6c517t30686/envvar40d929fadbe746ecagjbf6c515d306r6
```

Goal is to replace words `env.following.32.char.hash` into `{env}`, and similarly `envlabel.following.32.char.hash` into `{envlabel}` and similarly others.

I am trying to use regex in replace method,

```
to_replace_key = ['env', 'envlabel', 'envvar']

for word in to_replace_key:
    df['URL'] = df['URL'].str.replace(f"{word}\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w", f'{{{word}Id}}', regex=True)
```

Challenges:

1. `env` replaces `envlabels`
2. `keyword.following.32.char.hash` is located as a substring between `/` char or at the end of line

Expected output:

```
/someurl/{env}/user
/some/other/url/{envlabel}/{envvar}
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the regex `'(env(label|var)?)\w{32}'` which simply captures `env` and `label` if it is present. ie `?` ensures that `label` is captured if present. Replace the matched string with the first captured group. ie `\\1` within the curly braces.

```
  df['URL'].str.replace('(env(label|var)?)\w{32}', '{\\1}', regex=True)

0                     /someurl/{env}/end
1    /some/other/url/{envlabel}/{envvar}
```

### Edit:

If you have alot of items in the list, do:

```
pat = f"({'|'.join(sorted(to_replace_key, key = len,reverse = True))})\w{{{32}}}"

df['URL'].str.replace(pat, '{\\1}', regex=True)
Out[567]: 
0                     /someurl/{env}/end
1    /some/other/url/{envlabel}/{envvar}
Name: URL, dtype: object
```

Comment: apart from env, envlabel, envvar... i have other keywords, where should i add then in the re exp like file, folder ?

Comment: You can reduce them check the edit

Answer (score 1):

Don't loop, use:

```
df['URL'] = df['URL'].str.replace('(envlabel|envvar|env)\w{32}', r'{\1}', regex=True)
```

output:

```
                                   URL
0                   /someurl/{env}/end
1  /some/other/url/{envlabel}/{envvar}
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iqqWvm/1)